# Java JComboBox Select Last Value

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JComboBox` in which I have given the user the possibility to add a new value into that `JComboBox`, when they have added that value I want it so that value is now selected.

It automatically always sets the current selection to the first value in the `JComboBox`, is there a way I can set it to select the last value all the time, this would solve the problem

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can see what's wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jcomboBox.setSelectedValue("what you have added last");

---- or

jComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(jComboBox1.getItemCount()-1);
```

this is the code you are looking for try this.

Comment: Glad you agree with my suggestion. I didn't specify the method to get the item count to force the OP to actually take the time to read the combo box API.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way I can set it to select the last value all the time, this would solve the problem

```
comboBox.setSelectedIndex(...);
```

You just specify the index number you want to select which would be the number of items in the combo box - 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
JComboBox<String> test = new JComboBox<String>();
String value = "hello";
test.addItem(value);        
test.setSelectedItem(test);
```

Comment: A little description how this answers the OP would be a lot more helpful, don't you think?